# Conditional css - hover - overflow

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the text hidden when it's too long and show it when hovering on it.

The problem is that it also triggers when the text is not overflowing. How can I add as a condition *"If the text overflows then perform the translation, if the text doesn't overflow do not perform the translation"* ?

I would prefer a **css** solution rather than a **javascript** solution if possible to avoid unnecessary complexity *(I need to use it every time I have text)*.

**PS:** the solution can be **scss** markup.

```css
.case {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #444444;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.sp {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.case:hover .sp {
  transition: 1.3s;
  overflow: inherit;
  margin-left: -100%;
  width: auto;
  text-overflow: inherit;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="case">
  <span class="sp">Short text</span>
</div>

<div class="case">
  <span class="sp">Overflowing long text, so long that you can't read it at once!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that with only CSS. You'll need javascript.

Comment: You cant have a conditional :hover rule. You could possibly use use :hover to set overflow hidden to auto. If there is to much text overflow will show that text on hover. If there is not enough text to overflow then it should do nothing.

Comment: For what it's worth, one of the reasons you can't do this in CSS, is because it is generally considered a bad design to force the user to hover to read copy, then wait for it to scroll, hoping they can remember everything they read. It misses a couple of accessibility requirements too. I'm not saying this is a bad question, and we've all been forced to implement bad designs. But, just a recommendation, see if you can find a different design that's better for your users (and easier for you to implement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with only css, but the solution is not super clean, requires additional html markup (nested divs) and might probably break in the future, but if you insist on doing it withou js, you can see the solution below:

```css
.case {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #444444;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.sp {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.case:hover .sp {
  transition: 1.3s;
  overflow: inherit;
  margin-left: -100%;
  text-overflow: inherit;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.case:hover .case-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: 100%;
  transition: 1.3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.case-wrapper {
  text-overflow: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="case">
  <div class="case-wrapper">
  <span class="sp">Short text</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="case">
  <div class="case-wrapper">
  <span class="sp">Overflowing long text, so long that you can't read it at once!</span>
</div>
  </div>

<div class="case">
  <div class="case-wrapper">
  <span class="sp">It will always scroll all the way to the end and will stop there.</span>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please be aware that a js solution would be much cleaner, more maintainable, will have better support across different browsers, if you'll use this css only approach, then do it at your own risk.

Comment: It's a good input. Anyway I'm going to follow @Jon adams comment and use a different way to show the text to the user.

This answer indeed answer the question perfectly. About multi-browser compatibility, I guess there are tests to make to ensure that it works on chrome/firefox/edge

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea that rely on a flexbox trick but you will not have the ellipsis. The only drawback is that you need to define a big width and you may have a small delay at the start:

```css
.case {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #444444;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.sp {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  left:0;
  width: 250%; /* big enough */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end; /* Center to the end to have a left overflow */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sp:after {
  content:"";
  margin-left:auto; /* empty element to push content to the left */
}

.case:hover .sp {
  width: 100%; /* decrease the width to 100%*/
  transition:3s linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="case">
  <span class="sp">Short text</span>
</div>

<div class="case">
  <span class="sp">Overflowing long text, so long that you can't read it at once!</span>
</div>
```

To understand what is happening add some border and coloration:

```css
.case {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #444444;
  color: green;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position:relative;
}

.sp {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  left:0;
  width: 250%; /* big enough */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end; /* Center to the end to have a left overflow */
  white-space: nowrap;
  border:2px solid red;
}
.sp:after {
  content:"";
  width:2px;
  background:blue;
  margin-left:auto; /* empty element to push content to the left */
}

.case:hover .sp {
  width: 100%; /* decrease the width to 100%*/
  transition:3s linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="case">
  <span class="sp">Short text</span>
</div>

<div class="case">
  <span class="sp">Overflowing long text, so long that you can't read it at once!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Works. Unfortunately the ellipsis is gone. I think that @Jon Adams is right I should go for an other strategy to show the information to the user. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need javascript for this. If you want to keep it simple, you can do something like this (when the DOM is ready):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sp').forEach( el => {
  if (el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth ) el.classList.add('overflows');
})
```

And modify the animation selector like this:

```
.case:hover .sp.overflows {
```

The JS will check all `.sp` elements and add the `overflows` class when needed so it matches the selector.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYpPez